# Wrong code example

Tags: css

КОД не работает, css не распознает символы $, &, чем их можно заменить?
CSS:

```
$parallax-offset: 30vh;
$content-offset: 40vh;
$transition-speed: 1.2s;
$slide-number: 3;

html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100vh + $parallax-offset;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY($parallax-offset);
  @include transition($transition-speed, all, cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1));
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  }
  &:first-child {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/xZMOBTj.jpg);
    transform: translateY(-$parallax-offset / 2);
    .content-wrapper {
      transform: translateY($parallax-offset /2);
    }
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/4Aihmii.jpg);
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ugqtiLg.jpg);
  }
}

/* Set stacking context of slides */
@for $i from 1 to ($slide-number + 1) {
    .background:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        z-index: ($slide-number + 1) - $i; 
    }
}

.content {
  &-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateY($content-offset);
  will-change: transform;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  @include transition($transition-speed + .5, all, cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1));
  }
  &-title {
    font-size: 12vh;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
}

.background.up-scroll {
  transform: translate3d(0,-$parallax-offset / 2,0);
  .content-wrapper {
    transform: translateY($parallax-offset / 2);
  }
  + .background {
    transform: translate3d(0,$parallax-offset,0);
      .content-wrapper {
        transform: translateY($parallax-offset);
      }
    }
}

.background.down-scroll {
  transform: translate3d(0,-(100vh + $parallax-offset),0);
  .content-wrapper {
    transform: translateY($content-offset);
  }
  + .background:not(.down-scroll) {
    transform: translate3d(0,-$parallax-offset / 2,0);
      .content-wrapper {
        transform: translateY($parallax-offset / 2);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Потому что в `css` нету символов $, &

Comment: CSS и не должен этого распознавать. Пример, который вы привели, написан с использованием препроцессора SCSS.

Comment: А заголовок почему на английском?

Comment: @eccs0103, ну & уже скоро будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy `\`o\`.repeat(65535)`чень жду

Comment: Это код для **sass**, который должен быть впоследствии скомпилирован в css. В самом css переменных нет.

Comment: @T0xee.n17 , подскажите, возможно вы знаете как сделать parallax scroll на сайте?

Comment: @Nikita думаю что комментарии - не лучшее место для подобных вопросов. Вам лучше создать новый вопрос, **приведя в нём свою попытку и описание того что у вас не получилось**.

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что у вас не правильная запись переменных и не правильный их вывод.
Вот так правильно записывать переменные и выводить в CSS

```css
:root {
  --bs-title-color: orange;
  --bs-title-uppercase: uppercase;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--bs-title-color);
  text-transform: var(--bs-title-uppercase);
}
```

```html
<h1>Текст</h1>
```